# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController auto dismiss without showing addressbook book

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiinterfaceorientation, ipad, addressbookui

I am using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController for selection of address book contact by user. With this code behind action of a button:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
picker.view.frame=self.view.frame;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

When this code runs it rotates the Landscape UI to Portrait and eventually dismisses the controller that presents this ABPeoplePickerNavigationController.

I am getting this problem only in iOS 5, iPad 2. It's working fine with iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe in 5.x that landscape is supported for this picker.  However, try doing it via a different PresentationStyle.  I believe it should then work in landscape, i.e:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
picker.modalPresentationStyle  = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```